# Bash script: How to remote to a computer run a command and have output pipe to another computer?

Tags: macos, bash

I need to create a Bash Script that will be able to ssh into a computer or Machine B, run a command  and have the output piped back to a .txt file on machine A how do I go about doing this? Ultimately it will be list of computers that I will ssh to and run a command but all of the output will append to the same .txt file on Machine A.

UPDATE: Ok so I went and followed what That other Guy suggested and this is what seems to work:

```
File=/library/logs/file.txt
ssh -n username@<ip> "$(< testscript.sh)" > $File
```

What I need to do now is instead of manually entering an ip address, I need to have it read from a list of hostnames coming from a .txt file and have it place it in a variable that will substitute the ip address. An example would be: ssh username@Variable in which "Variable" will be changing each time a word is read from a file containing hostnames. Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: `ssh -n user@machineB somecommand > file.txt`

Comment: I have more than one command, this is what I need to query on each machine: echo Hostname=$(hostname) LastChecked=$(date)>> $File

ls -l /applications/utilities/Disk\ Utility.app/contents/Plugins | grep Partition.dumodule | awk -v a=Username= -v b=DateModified= '{print a $3, b $6, $7, $8}' >> $File                                                         Can I just put this all where you have "some command" at and it will run?

Comment: With appropriate quoting, yes.

Comment: What appropriate quoting do I use? Im mediocre at bash scripting so I need as much guidance as possible haha

Comment: In that case, the easiest way is to put those commands in a file, make sure they run fine with `bash thatfile` on your local machine, and then `ssh -n user@machineB "$(< thatfile)"`

Comment: so it will run that file on the remote computer and then put " > file.txt" at the end of that so the output is piped to machine A?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
ssh userB@machineB "some command" | ssh userA@machineA "cat - >> file.txt"
```

With your commands:

```
ssh userB@machineB <<'END' | ssh userA@machineA "cat - >> file.txt"
echo Hostname=$(hostname) LastChecked=$(date)
ls -l /applications/utilities/Disk\ Utility.app/contents/Plugins/*Partition.dumodule* | awk '{printf "Username=%s DateModified=%s %s %s\n", $3, $6, $7, $8}'
END
```

You could replace the `ls -l | awk` pipeline with a single `stat` call, but it appears that the [OSX stat](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) does not have a way to return the user name, only the user id

Comment: Thank you for the input glenn, I tried what you said and I am getting "line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `|'" error message

Comment: There appears to be an extra `'` before the final `|`. Try removing that.

Comment: Yeah, the single quotes for the awk body were poorly embedded in the single quotes for the whole remote script. bad on me. Updated to a quoted heredoc.